# FInd minimum element in stack in O(1) time C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack, c++14, minimum

Here I am finding the minimum element in a stack using `mini()` function. While pushing and popping in the stack, I set `min1` and `min2` logically. In which cases would my code fail? What are the problems with my code?

The push function sets `min1` and `min2` variables. `min1` corresponds to the least element and `min2` corresponds to 2nd least element in the stack. In the pop if popped element is equal to mini then I update `min1` to 2nd least value before pop and carry on. So at all times `min1` has least value in the stack.

```
class stac
{
public:
void push(int item)
{
if(top>=STACK_SIZE-1)
{
    cout<<"Full"<<endl;
    return;
}
else
{
    if(item<min1)
    {
        min2 = min1;
        min1=item;
    }
    s[++top]=item;
    return;
}
}

void pop()
{
if(top==-1)
{
    cout<<"Empty"<<endl;
    return;
}
else
{
    if(s[top]==min1)
    {
        min1=min2;
    }
    top--;
    return;
}
}
void mini()
 {
   if(top==-1)
  {
      cout<<"no minimum"<<endl;
      return;
}
else
{
    cout<<min1<<endl;
}
}


private:
int min1 = INT_MAX;
int min2;
int s[STACK_SIZE];
int top = -1;
};
int main()
{

  stac s1;

  s1.push(5);
  s1.push(2);
  s1.push(9);
  s1.push(1);
  s1.push(24);
  s1.push(-1);
  s1.push(-87);
  s1.push(23);
  s1.mini();
  s1.display();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suppose I push three elements, each one smaller than the previous (say, 3, 2 and 1); then pop two of them. What would be the value of the smallest element in the stack at that point, and what would be the value of `min1`?

Comment: In `main` you should probably call `s1.pop` a few times before calling `s1.mini`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are saving last two minimum only. After popping two miminum number, you do not know which is minimum now.

Keep two stacks, one regular, another for keeping current minimum. While pushing always push current minimum on this minimum stack. So, you will always have minumum value on top of current stack. While popping, pop from both stacks.

Or on same stack, you can always push two element, new element along with new minumum. and while poping, pop two element, one current element, another current minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

#define STACK_SIZE 10000

class stac
{
public:

stac() : top(-1)
{

}

void push(int item)
{
if(top>=STACK_SIZE-1)
{
    cout<<"Full"<<endl;
    return;
}
else
{
    cout << "top is" << top << endl;
    int currentmin = min[top];
    top ++;
    if(top == 0 || item < currentmin )
    {
        min[top] = item; // New minimum
    }
    else
    {
       min[top] = currentmin; //keep current minimum
    }

    s[top]=item;

    return;
}
}

void pop()
{
if(top==-1)
{
    cout<<"Empty"<<endl;
    return;
}
else
{
    top--;
    return;
}
}
void mini()
 {
   if(top==-1)
  {
      cout<<"no minimum"<<endl;
      return;
}
else
{
    cout<<min[top]<<endl;
}
}

void display()
{
  int i = top;
  cout << "elememt stack:";

  while(i)
  {
     cout << s[i--] << " " ;

  }

  i = top;
  cout << "\nmin stack:";

  while(i)
  {
     cout << min[i--] << " " ;
  }
  cout << "\n";
}

private:

int s[STACK_SIZE];
int min[STACK_SIZE];
int top = -1;
};
int main()
{

  stac s1;

  s1.push(5);
  s1.push(2);
  s1.push(9);
  s1.push(1);
  s1.push(24);
  s1.push(-1);
  s1.push(-87);
  s1.push(23);
  s1.mini();
  s1.display();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could have additional metadata as part of the data in the stack, you could store the most minimal data encountered up until that point in the metadata. No matter how many elements you pop, the metadata of the top of the stack would have the minimal value.